# Corner missing when drawing a square

Tags: c#, drawing

I just have no idea why I am not getting a perfect square when drawing. I have these `PointF's`:

- [0] = {X = 1.80000067 Y = 101.8}
- [1] = {X = 1.80000067 Y = 103.6}
- [2] = {X = 101.8 Y = 103.6}
- [3] = {X = 101.8 Y = 101.8}

And I am using this code to draw:

```
Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
Graphis g = Graphics.FromImage(pic);

g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black,pointsUpThere);
```

I am using `DrawPolygon()` because those aren't always corners of a square. It can be more complex shapes.

So, instead of a square in this example, I get this:
[image]

I don't get it, wheres the problem?

Best regards!

Comment: Does it work if you don't use floating points/round them?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it, but is it possible that you inverted the two Y's in point[2] and point[3] ?

Comment: Try referencing this `MSDN` page looks like you're not creating any new points http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0c4s09.aspx

Comment: Translating those small numbers into pixels isn't perfect.  Try adding `g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` before the DrawPolygon line.

Comment: @tijizor I think you are correct, the points don't make sense.

Comment: Perhaps try removing the last point? So you only provide 3? DrawPolygon's supposed to close the poly automatically in that case.

Comment: A rectangle requires *five* points when drawn as a polygon, the last point must match the first.  Using four points will produce artifacts with fat pens.  Or just use DrawRectangle.

Comment: What do you mean they dont make sense?
This array already doesnt contain the first point as the last.
I have already tried adding the first point as the last, but the results are the same.

Setting AntiAlias works, it does fill that missing edge, but it also draws few pixels more brighter then the others, which I dont really want.

Comment: I am just gonna use AntiAlias, since it only makes few pixels brighter thats not such a big deal. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the X difference between points is 100 (hundred).
The Y difference is 1.8.

Sounds like a veeeeeeery long rectangle.

Comment: That isn't really an answer...more of a comment.

Comment: @SteveWellens - it explains why the output isn't a perfect **square**. But the question is really about why there is a gap in the rectangle.